# why does my dropzonejs file upload look like this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropzone.js

whats wrong with my dropzone?
how come the it's weird like that?

and how do we fix it?

[image]

the `check` and `X` icon are like that and there is no progress bar?

here is my **HTML**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.2.0/dropzone.css">

    <div  id="drop_zone_box">
        <div id="preview-container"></div>
    </div> 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.2.0/dropzone.js"</script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='profile/scripts/profile.js') }}"></script>
```

contents of **profile.js**:

```
$(function() {

 var dropZone = new Dropzone("#drop_zone_box",{
            url: "/",
            previewsContainer:"#preview-container",
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            autoDiscover: false,
            clickable: true,
            autoProcessQueue:false,

        });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

turns out. you need to add a `dropzone` class to the html element you want to become the dropzone

so by simply adding the `dropzone` class

```
<div  id="drop_zone_box" class="dropzone>
    <div id="preview-container"></div>
</div>
```

it will work

I was under the impression that you didn't need to because you made a `dropzone` object in the js file to initialize `dropzone`